# Check if checkbox is selected using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am inserting checkbox using JQuery. When a user click "Add Checkbox" button, the checkbox appears. Now once the user selects this checkbox, I want to get the details i.e value or text of that particular checkbox. How to do that ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-check').click(function() {
    $('.getcheckbox').append('<input class="check-box" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>');
  });

  $('.check-box').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      console.log("tick");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="getcheckbox">

</div>
<button class="btn-check">Add Checkbox</button>
```

Comment: You mean if the checkbox is checked? Select means to click it once but a checkbox can be clicked an infinite amount of times.

Comment: Use `$('.getcheckbox').on('change', '.check-box', function() { if ($(this).is(':checked')) { console.log($(this).val()); } });`

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. It worked